# Parameterising an import statement

Tags: python

I maintain a Python module that wraps and exposes the functionality of a DLL (also maintained by me).  The interfacing with the DLL uses ctypes.

This all works wonderfully thanks to the wonders of ctypes.  However, as I am by no means a Python expert, there are some parts of the Python that I feel are not *idiomatic*.

In particular I offer control of the DLL location to the user of the module. The DLL is loaded during the import of the module. I do this because I want to switch behaviour based on the capability of the DLL, and I need to load the DLL in order to query its behaviour.

By default, the DLL load relies of the DLL search path to locate the DLL. I would like to be able to allow the user to specify a full path to the DLL, should they wish to pick out a particular version.

At the moment I do this by using an environment variable but I recognise that this is a rather grotesque way to do it. What I'm looking for is a *canonical* or *idiomatic* Python way for the module importer to pass some information to the module which can be accessed at module import time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should defer loading the DLL to the point where it's actually used for the first time, and offer an optional function initialize:

```
_initialized=False
def initialize(path=None):
  if _initialized:
    if path:
      raise ValueError, "initialize called after first use"
    return
  if path is None:
    path = default_path
  load_dll(path)
  determine_features()
```

Then, call `initialized()` in all API you offer. This gives the user a chance to override it, but if they don't, it will continue to work as it does today (you can even preserve support for the environment variable).

If you are willing to change the API, use classes:

```
class DLLAPI:
  def __init__(self, path=None):
    ...
```

Users would have to create a DLLAPI instance, and may or may not pass a DLL path. That should allow to even use different DLLs simultaneously.

Comment: +1, import with minimal use, have a initialise function that handles more complicated stuff. for example, pygame.init()

Comment: +1 Thanks Martin. This will certainly get the job done. The only downside is that I have to call the lazy initialisation routine on every entry point. Thankfully I have a relatively small number of entry points.

Comment: @Martin I've tried this approach and I'm not hopeful that it will solve my problem easily. It's quite possibly my entire approach in building this module that is wrong, but I'll try to explain a little more. The capabilities of the DLL really need to be known at module import time. My module defines various classes and those classes need to know the DLL capabilities at the point where they are defined (i.e. import time). So, I'm still stuck, but it's probably my own lack of understanding that's to blame.

Comment: @David Heffernan: If you want further help on that, you'll have to edit your question to provide more details. For example, how specifically need the classes to change? (give specific examples from the actual code). I'm fairly certain it can be done lazily, all of it.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks. It might take me a little time to get such code ready. I'd like to experiment a little further and cut it down to the bare bones - don't want to throw a wall of code out there!

Comment: @Martin Right, I think I can see what I need to do now. I just need to get a better understanding of what runs at module import time, but I think I'm there now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This code is taken from this page http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments
It adds some paths to explores :

```
ALLDIRS = ['usr/local/pythonenv/PYLONS-1/lib/python2.5/site-packages']

import sys 
import site 

# Remember original sys.path.
prev_sys_path = list(sys.path) 

# Add each new site-packages directory.
for directory in ALLDIRS:
  site.addsitedir(directory)

# Reorder sys.path so new directories at the front.
new_sys_path = [] 
for item in list(sys.path): 
    if item not in prev_sys_path: 
        new_sys_path.append(item) 
        sys.path.remove(item) 
sys.path[:0] = new_sys_path
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's not quite what I was looking for. I guess I didn't make my question quite clear enough. Anyway, thanks all the same.